# PHP custom checkout fields for each product WooCommerce WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I need some help if anyone can :D 
I need to have different custom fields in Checkout for each product. I managed to do that with php in funtions.php . So far so good, but all the fields that I added appear in random places that's why I added priority for the fields, and there is a problem. The checkout for the product that doesn't have every field, will get empty  fields because of the priority setting. How can I fix that? (see screenshot)

[image]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        if( $product_id == 775 ) {
            $fields['billing']['billing_masa'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Puteti lua 3-4 mese pe zi la intrvale egale de timp?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_intoleranta'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Aveti intoleranta la lactoza?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_intoleranta2'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Aveti alimente pe care nu le tolerati?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_variante'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Doriti sa primiti mai multe variante de alimente pentru a va alcatui masa dupa placul dumneavoastra?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_boli'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Suferiti de diabet, hipertensiune, afectiuni digestive?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_rutina'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Descrieti rutina alimentara zilnica de pana acum.', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
        }
        if( $product_id == 776 ) {
            $fields['billing']['billing_masa'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Puteti lua 3-4 mese pe zi la intrvale egale de timp?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_intoleranta'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Aveti intoleranta la lactoza?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_intoleranta2'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Aveti alimente pe care nu le tolerati?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_variante'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Doriti sa primiti mai multe variante de alimente pentru a va alcatui masa dupa placul dumneavoastra?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_boli'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Suferiti de diabet, hipertensiune, afectiuni digestive?', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_rutina'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Descrieti rutina alimentara zilnica de pana acum.', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_rutina2'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Descrieti o zi din viata dvs din punct de vedere alimentar.', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
            $fields['billing']['billing_istoric'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Istoricul dvs medical include interventii de natura digestiva (olecistectomie, litiaza biliara, rezectie gastrica)? Daca da, mentionati ca s-a realizat.', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => true ,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
        } 
    }
    return $fields;
}

/*
Priority
 */

function js_sort_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_masa']['priority'] = 111;
    $fields['billing']['billing_intoleranta']['priority'] = 112;
    $fields['billing']['billing_intoleranta2']['priority'] = 113;
    $fields['billing']['billing_variante']['priority'] = 114;
    $fields['billing']['billing_boli']['priority'] = 115;
    $fields['billing']['billing_rutina']['priority'] = 116;
    $fields['billing']['billing_rutina2']['priority'] = 117;
    $fields['billing']['billing_istoric']['priority'] = 118;
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'js_sort_checkout_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0):

did you look in the template, there is maybe a solution inside. I had a similar problem i solved this way.
Best regards.
Olivier Angelloz-Pessey

Comment: It better would be a comment!

Comment: can you give the solution?  were to change and how? thank you :D